# Unable to read timstamp value in pyspark from Hive (spark 1.6.1)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am trying to read a Hive Table having a date column with datatype as `timestamp, length=9`. 
my code looks something like the following -

```
df = hc.sql("select * from schema.table")
```

It can read all other columns (datatype = `varchar`).

It either reads `null` or gives `none` in date column

I have printed the `df.dtypes` and found that the dataframe schema was inferred correctly and date columns have `timestamp` datatype

surprisingly the same code works in `notebook`, only fails in `spark-shell` environment.

Can someone guide me what could be wrong or limitation that renders this error and how could I rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem in spark, Where It will display as null when the datatype is timestamp, Its a bug. There is a way to get around it where you have to read that date column as string using something like this `to_char(Column_name ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS') as column_name,` and then cast it to timestamp. If you can tell me the source type and the tool you used to pull the data like sqoop or are you getting the data in some form of files ?? I can help you better.

Comment: Thanks.. I am coding within Spark shell in IBM Big Insights tool. Reading data from Hive tables (Big Insights) using Hive Context